# Restrict message queue publisher based on message content

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, message-queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I need to organize a message queue that has multiple publishers.
Each publisher should only be allowed to publish a message with a specific header or part of message body (e.g. json field).

Having multiple separate message queues per publisher is a clear solution, however I would like to avoid this, because new publishers are going to be added regularly.

I am considering all major message brokers:

- SNS
- SQS
- Kafka
- RabbitMQ

AWS is used as cloud infrastructure.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Put an if statement in your publisher codes that parses and filters the data. None of these natively offer server-side record validation or filtering

Comment: Could do using an intermediary synchronous step to verify it; eg run it through API Gateway.